# How do I send a username and password to git's credential user prompt from my powershell script?

Tags: git, powershell, git-credential-manager

I am using a script to checkout and update a list of branches. I am able to [retrieve git credentials from the Windows Credential Manager](http://www.automatedops.com/blog/2013/06/07/get-storedcredentials-module/) and I need to respond to the prompt for git credentials using them.

How do I send text to the git user prompt from my script? I have tried ECHO and piping the text directly to the git call but neither method is working (the prompt still appears and nothing is typed in).

```
[PSCredential]$cred = Get-StoredCredential gitCred
$cur_head = "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
$cred.Username |  git pull origin ${cur_head} -q
```

or

```
ECHO $cred.Username |  git pull origin ${cur_head} -q
```

Note: I am using the windows credential manager to store my git credentials, I do not want to put them in any other credential manager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a couple of my scripts I use this:

```sh
$env:GIT_USER="."
$env:GIT_PASS=$token
Invoke-Git config --global credential.helper "!f() { echo \`"username=`${GIT_USER}`npassword=`${GIT_PASS}\`"; }; f"
```

To pass an arbitrary username/password from the environment of the running powershell session. The code above passes a Personal Access Token, but you can easily set the environment variables with a different value.

You could also install the [Git Cretential Manager (Core)](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager), which would automatically fetch the creds from the windows credential manager.

For those interested in the implementation of `Invoke-Git`:

```sh
function Invoke-Git {
<#
.Synopsis
Wrapper function that deals with PowerShells peculiar error output when Git uses the error stream.
.Example
Invoke-Git ThrowError
$LASTEXITCODE
#>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
        [string[]]$Arguments
    )

    & {
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param(
            [parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
            [string[]]$InnerArgs
        )
        if ($isDebug) { "git $InnerArgs" }
        git $InnerArgs
    } -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable fail @Arguments

    if ($fail) {
        $fail.Exception
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice, but it's worth clarifying what `Invoke-Git` is, given that it's not a standard cmdlet. Is it just a wrapper around the `git` executable with error handling? Out of curiosity: what is the benefit of defining the `f` function instead of using just the `echo` command alone?

Comment: This looks useful over all, I would also like to know where `Invoke-Git` is coming from!

Comment: Subbing `git` for `Invoke-Git` allows me to run it, and it works perfectly

Comment: Why a function... No clue, I'm not a king in bash and someone pointed me to this ages ago and it works. Why change it ;).

Comment: @jessehouwing, thanks for updating. Fair enough re function :) From what I can tell (using direct invocation of `git`), the following will do (the `!` prefix tells `git` that the value is a shell command): ``git config --global credential.helper "! echo \`"username=`${GIT_USER}`npassword=`${GIT_PASS}\`""``